# Force Child to Float Parent Width

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of questions regarding forcing a nested div child to fill the width of its parent container, but my question is how to force a child div with a natural flow width that is larger than its parent container (for example, the child div contains a text node that ends up stretching the child beyond the width of the parent container) to maintain its parents width?

A simple non-dynamic solution is to set a width on the parent, but what if the width is not pre-determined (for responsive reasons)? Is there some tag I can add to the child elements to make sure they wrap their content and force the element to stay within the width of the parent?`

```
<div class="parent"> //Width is not set
    <div class="child">Here might be a long string of dynamic text</div>
</div>
```

I understand that by setting a width on the parent element would fix this issue, but in my case I cannot do that because the element is set to resize its width depending on screen size. So for instance if the user is on a phone and turns from portrait to landscape, the parent element must be able to resize and i'd prefer to not have to use javascript for that.

I should also mention that in my particular situation, the parent element is a float. I'm not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the problem?

Comment: My first reaction is that this is the natural behavior of inner divs, so perhaps I'm not understanding the question. Could you post a link to an example where things are not working as you want? By default, the child div above will fill the container and the text will wrap as needed.

Comment: May be you can use a fixed width for parent `div` using media queries for device specific size and can set the child `div` width `100%`, IMO.

Comment: Its a little complex to replicate quickly but i'll attempt to explain. The parent is a menu that can be toggled hidden/visible. The menu has sub menus that are dynamically filled when clicked. Some testing revealed the problem is because the parent is a float. But it needs to remain a float...

Comment: Did you try floating the child?

Comment: Yes, makes the problem worse actually. Basically its only an issue when a text string of a single word in the child is longer than the width. Floating forces the entire string (all words) onto a single line and actually makes the child width even larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Sheikh Heera's comment on the question, the only way to achieve this is by actually setting a width on the parent element. In my situation the most robust solution was to use media queries to set the width per the screen size accordingly. Its not exactly the solution i'd like, but its the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the max-width CSS property? Div, specifically the child here, is a block level element and should confine itself to the parent div's width. If the code below doesn't help we will need you to expand on what you are working on.

```
.child {
max-width: 100%
}
```

Try that in your stylesheet and behold the css magic! Cheers

Comment: this would also work for the parent if it is inside a container

Comment: Max-width doesn't work because the parent is a float and doesn't have a set width. Unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have an objection to using JavaScript? It works in all modern browsers and could be easily implemented. Let me know if you want some help writing a function for your resize

Answer (score 0):

You can contain the child size within the parent by using overflow style:

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Probably because the parent is a float element without a set width? Wouldn't overflow just hide the content anyways? I need the content to show, just preferably break the words and wrap down as needed.

Comment: if the text is directly in parent div, it will hide the text if it's larger, but with the child div containing the text, the child div resizes to the parent size and the text is wrapped.

Comment: Hmm...not working for me. Maybe because the parent is a float?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to achieve.

css

```
.parent {float:left; width:100%}
.child {display:block}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnfke/)

hope this help..

Comment: You do have a set width here. The jsFiddle says it doesn't, but its set to 100%.

Comment: can give example of what you trying to achieve.